# Change react antd DatePicker language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, locale, antd

How Can I set the antd Datepicker language to french?

I tried this :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import moment from "moment";
import { DatePicker, Space, ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import frFR from "antd/lib/locale/fr_FR";

function onChange(date, dateString) {
  console.log(date, dateString);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Space direction="vertical">
    <ConfigProvider locale={frFR}>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        defaultValue={moment("2015-01-01", "YYYY-MM-DD")}
      />
    </ConfigProvider>
  </Space>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

The preview language is still in English.

Here is a running code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-datepicker-language-n9ue7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the ant design doc

```
import 'moment/locale/zh-cn';
import locale from 'antd/es/date-picker/locale/zh_CN';

<DatePicker locale={locale} />;
```

https://ant.design/components/date-picker#localization

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to make it work for the French language?

Comment: unsure what french variant you want, but you can replace `zh_CN` with `fr_BE` as an example: https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php

Comment: I changed the imports to this: import 'moment/locale/fr';
import locale from 'antd/es/date-picker/locale/fr_FR'